# Handle HEIC / HEIF image in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, file, heic

I want to display HEIC / HEIF image from my gallery using Image.memory. But it show error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFYfD.png) everytime I select .heic file. It works fine in .jpg or .jpeg.

here is my code for selecting the file

```
Uint8List? pickedPhotoFile;
FilePickerResult? selectedFile;

Future<void> selectFile() async {
    selectedFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.any);

    if (selectedFile != null) {
      pickedPhotoFile = selectedFile!.files.single.bytes;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

And this is how i display the image

```
Image.memory(
      pickedPhotoFile!,
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
    );
```

Any help would be appreciated